# What can we do in order to have a program to be runnable in the future architecture and OS?

Tags: architecture, operating-system

I raised this question up because I have seen Windows 7 64 bits able to run several 32 bits program without any problem; of course, some run with problems and some refuse to run at all.

I am not sure why some 32 bits program can run just fine on 64 bits, but for us, in the future, say, if we have a 128 bit architecture and OS released in the future, what can we do in term of programming if we want our program to be able to run in a different bit architecture? Or is it not a programmer's job?

Comment: Are you asking about executables built for one platform working on another, or about source code being buildable on different platforms?  The former is not the programmer's job, the latter is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two possible questions here:  what to do to allow the binary to run, and what to do to allow the source to compile and run.

There isn't that much you can do to make the binary future-proof.  Go strictly by the published API, and avoid using anything undocumented.  It will run if the future system supports it, and the future system is far more likely to support the standard API than anything undocumented.  This was the problem with many early Macintosh programs:  instead of using the API (which was clumsy for some things early on), they used shortcuts that worked in OS 5 or whatever, and didn't in OS 7.

This advice is mostly for C and C++, as languages like Java define things much better.  Any pure Java program should run fine on any later JVM.  (Yes, this has its own costs.)

Abstract out all the architecture-dependent stuff you can.  Use types like `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` in C and C++, rather than any type of integer.

When you need a type of a particular bit size, don't give it a type like `int` or `long`.  Use typedefs.  There's a C99 header with useful typedefs for the purpose, but you can always have something like `typedef int int32_t` and change the `int` later, as needed, in one obvious place rather than scattered around the program in hard-to-find places.

Try to encapsulate OS calls, since those could change in a future architecture.  If you must do anything with an undocumented OS feature, document it very noticeably.

If your program has anything to do with networking, assume nothing about the byte order.  Networking byte order is unlikely to change, but your program might wind up on a chip with a different architecture (cf. the Macintosh, which has used three different architectures in its time).

In general, assume as little as you can get away with.  Use types specifically designated for machine-dependent things, and use them consistently.  Do everything outside the program as written in the most formal, standard, and documented way possible.

Comment: That was a really good answer, it captured a lot of what I attempted to say in much greater detail +1 for you sir

Answer (score 1):

I've yet to see a mature application that does not end up with implicit assumptions about bit size. It creeps in whatever you do.

Also you cannot predict what the OS supplier will do to mess up their API either. At best you can only wrap and hide the external API into your own libraries.

Macroizing or typedefing the basic types doesn't work because people will invariably use the macros or typedefs for everything, and you are back to the same position you were originally where you can't differentiate what should be the new int size and what really does need to be 64 or 32 bits.

What you can do is save numeric values in ascii that does fix some of the file format issues.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much an application developer can do preemptively guarantee compatibility with the next major architectural change, but these are some general things one can do to increase the likelihood of remaining compatible, at least as far as new operating system releases are concerned.

1. Take dependencies on documented APIs

   This may seam like an obvious point but using undocumented or private APIs makes you susceptible to changes in internal implementation details which do frequently change. You may be shielded from some of these changes by using public interfaces which are more likely to remain compatible in some way when internal changes are made.
2. Don't depend on implementation details or side effects

   This includes things like not making assumptions about structure sizes or  using reserved parameters for your own purposes because you never know what they could mean in the future.
3. Don't make too many assumptions about the platform
   Things like overly specific operating system version number checks can prevent an application from running where it may be able to. I'm not sure if this is a good example of this but I've seen many apps not work on Windows Server because they were explicitly checking for NT 5.1 (Windows XP)
4. Try to keep abreast of upcoming changes to the platforms and technologies you use now

   Knowing ahead of time what platform changes are coming can help a great deal in making sure your app can run on the new platform. If you know that in six months from now the driver model is changing then you may be able to rewrite it before the need for the new driver becomes pressing provided your vendor can give you enough warning and information of course.

   In recent years Microsoft has become increasingly more open with respect to publicizing new operating system resources early, the vista pre-release builds were a good example of this. If you work with windows MSDN can be an invaluable resource in this regard

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, or even useful but I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In this particular situation, is not up to you as developer to provide binary compatibility but that's up to the OS manufacturer.

The manufacturer can ignore this compatibility need and your program won't run anymore. But everyone will hate him.

So that's not a programmer task.

What you can do to minimize the risk ( furthermore when you're targeting different platforms ) is to use standard libraries and/or choose a cross platform programming language like Java.

Answer (score 1):

Things you can do to keep your software running in any new platform:

- If you use interpreted languages you get portability when the interpreter/vm is ported.
- Rely on hardware emulation.
- Write portable code and provide means to recompile it.

About why 32bit application can run unmodified in 64bit systems, assuming you're talking about AMD64, it's because the HW architects had that in mind and provided a [legacy mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD64#Operating_modes).